# shell script error in unix

Tags: shell, unix

what does using 1# for a directory do here?

> cpfile=${1#/usr/newconfig} ls -l $cpfile | read var1 echo var1

I am tryiing to understand the script, but I cannot find any resource that would help me ascertain the meaning of this command.

Comment: Maybe you mean ${!#/usr/newconfig}

Comment: Read [the `bash` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) and search for "Parameter expansion" and "Remove matching prefix pattern". The `1` in this case is the first argument to the script (i.e. `$1`).

Answer (score 0):

In general, variables can be modified with `#`, which removes a leading string.  If `a` is a variable with content `foobar`, then `${a#foo}` strips the `foo` and evaluates to `bar`.  In your case, $1 is a positional parameter, and `${1#/usr/newconfig}` is the value of that string with "/usr/newconfig" removed from the start.  If it does not match, the expression evaluates to the same string as $1.

However, this script has a rather significant issue in that it assigns cpfile in the environment of the `ls` that is run, but `ls` does not receive it as an argument.  As a result, `ls` is going to operate on the current working directory rather than the directory passed as an argument to the script. (unless `cpfile` is assigned previously in the script somewhere.)